# Probability of finding $ε$-approximate median of an array

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm given an array $A$ = ($a_1, a_2, \cdots a_n$), where n is uneven. For an element $a_i$ we denote its position in the array with $p(a_i)$. This element would be an $ε$-approximate median of the array, if after we sort it, the following inequality holds:

$$\frac12 ((1 - ε) × n) < p(a_i) \leqslant \frac12 ((1 + ε) × n)$$
For example, the array $1,2,\cdots,9$ would have $4,5,6$ as $\dfrac13$-approximate medians.

My task is to analyze the following randomized algorithm, which finds an $ε$-approximate median of the array in constant time:

> Choose $2k + 1$ elements of the array $A$: $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{2k+1}$, where each element is chosen uniformly randomly and independently of all the others (it is possible for an element to repeat). Using the algorithm for finding a median of an array in linear time (QuickSelect) output the median of the array the elements $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{2k+1}$ form.

I'm also given the following two random variables:

$K$: number of elements in $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{2k+1}$, which are smaller or equal to the $\dfrac12 ((1-ε)×n)$-biggest element in the original array 
$A$.

$G$: number of elements in $b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_{2k+1}$, which are bigger than the $\dfrac12 ((1+ε)×n)$-biggest element in the original array $A$.

What I have to do is find the best possible upper bounds for 
$$P(K \geqslant (1 + ε) E(K))$$
and 
$$P(G \geqslant (1 + ε) E(G)),$$
where $E(K)$ and $E(G)$ are the expected values for the random variables. I also have to find a bound for the probability the algorithm will be successful, which depends only on $k$, not on $n$, $E(K)$ or $E(G)$.

What I have done so far: I computed the expected values for the two random variables. I believe they are binomially distributed, so for example for $K$ I have $2k + 1$ events each with probability $\dfrac12(1-ε)$ to happen, so 
$$E(K) = (2k + 1) × \dfrac12 (1 - ε).$$
$E(G)$ turns out to be the same. Then I tried computing the two upper bounds, mentioned above with the Markov, Chebyshev and Chernoff inequalities:

Markov: 
$$P(K \geqslant (1 + ε) E(K)) \leqslant \frac1{1 + ε},$$
Chebyshev (might be false):
$$P(|K - E(K)| \geqslant εE(K)) \leqslant \frac{\operatorname{Var}(K)}{ε^2 × (E(K))^2} = \frac{1}{ε(2k + 1)},$$
Chernoff:
$$P(K \geqslant (1 + ε) E(K)) \leqslant \exp\left( -\frac13 ε^2 E(K) \right).$$
Are these correct? If they are, am I correct that Chebyshev is the best one? How do I continue with finding the probability of success of the algorithm?

Thank you :)

Comment: You seem to be using $p$ both for the element and for its position?

Comment: What I mean is that the element p is bigger than the ((1−ε) * n)/2-biggest element and smaller or equal than the ((1+ε) * n)/2-biggest element of the array. So, the value of element p is a median of the array with some margin of error.

Comment: The point is not so much to explain to me in a comment what you mean, but to clarify the question so that people who read it will understand it. The question shouldn't rely on the comments to be understood. (Comments may not be displayed later when further comments are added.) Regardless of that, I still don't understand the inequality in the question, even in light of your comment. It still seems, as I wrote, that you're using $p$ both as the value of an element and as its position.

Comment: In the first inequality in the question, you compare $p$ with expressions involving $n$, which seems to indicate position; but you call it an "element"; not a position. Or perhaps you forgot to state that the $n$ elements are the numbers $1$ through $n$?

Comment: Edited, hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: It is, much clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literature credits *Manku et al.* for solving this problem in section 5: "*A Sampling based Algorithm*" of their paper [DOI:10.1145/276304.276342](http://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Esamir/498/manku.pdf): *Approximate Medians and other Quantiles in One Pass and with Limited Memory*.
**Beware** that the OP notes $ε$ the whole confidence interval, whereas *Manku et al.* note $ε$ only half the confidence interval.

First observation is that if $K$ and $G$ are both less than $\frac{2k+1}2$, then the median of the sample is an ε-approximate median.
Taking $1-δ$ as the wanted level of confidence that the sample is good, then it's enough to ensure that both:
$$
P(K \ge \frac{2k+1}2) \le \fracδ2\\
P(G \ge \frac{2k+1}2) \le \fracδ2
$$

Because $K$ and $G$ are both independent Bernoulli trials of $2k+1$ events, each with probability $\frac{1−ε}2$ to happen, $E(K) = E(G) = (1-ε)\frac{2k+1}2$, therefore:
$$
P(K \ge \frac{2k+1}2) = P(K - E(K) \ge ε\frac{2k+1}2)\\
P(G \ge \frac{2k+1}2) = P(G - E(G) \ge ε\frac{2k+1}2)
$$

Then, by [Hoeffding's inequality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4029.pdf):
$$
P(K \ge \frac{2k+1}2) \le \exp(\frac{-2ε²(\frac{2k+1}2)²}{2k+1})\\
P(G \ge \frac{2k+1}2) \le \exp(\frac{-2ε²(\frac{2k+1}2)²}{2k+1})
$$
(Here I believe there's a typo in the paper and that $S²$ should be $\frac{S²}S$, hopefully the error is no longer present when the authors determine $S$ from $ε$ and $δ$.)

By the union bound, it's then enough to ensure:
$$
\exp(-ε²\frac{2k+1}2) \le \fracδ2
$$

Then, fixing $δ$ enables to determine a lower-bound for the number of samples, also independent of $n$:
$$
\frac2{ε²}\log(\frac2{δ}) \le 2k+1
$$

As a side note, there's also a related paper [DOI: 10.3150/14-BEJ605](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.4029.pdf) by Rémi Bardenet and Odalric-Ambrym Maillard: *Concentration inequalities for sampling without replacement*, stating that the sampling without replacement enables to improve Hoeffding’s bound with an Hoeffding–Serfling bound depending upon $n$ which is close for a sample size below $\frac{n}2$, but decreases to zero above this point, outperforming Hoeffding’s bound.